# Spring 3.2 Jackson2 (400 Bad request)

Tags: spring-mvc

I know spring 3.2 does convert a json to a list of objects with RequestBody annotation. Its not working for me. I can use regular Jackson object mapper to do it. Just checking if any one can help me.. Below is my json and controller method

```
[{"uniqueJqGridId":"1","fileProcessingDate":"2012-09-24","createdTimeStamp":"1348569180191","csoCode":"A-A  ","cycleDate":"2012-09-24","accountDate":"2012-10-02","originName":"NCAA                     ","amount":"-95996.33","policyNumber":"C               ","transactionCode":"PCH","id":"1"}]

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/washTransactions", headers="Content-Type=application/json")  
public @ResponseBody RequestStatus washTransactions(@RequestBody List<ReconPolicy> policiesToWash)throws Exception{
    reconciliationService.applyWashToTransactions(policiesToWash,getCurrentUser());
    return new RequestStatus(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing Java's Type Erasure problem. Spring is not able to pass the exact class type to the method so it's actually getting something like `List<?> policiesToWash`.

A workaround would be to create a class like

```
public class WashablePolishes extends ArrayList<ReconPolicy>
```

This way spring will retain the type through the super type chain.

or you could change your method to

```
public @ResponseBody RequestStatus washTransactions(@RequestBody ReconPolicy[] policiesToWash) throws Exception {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you reply Varun. Starting from Spring 3.2,There is no type erasure problem. I found the issue after enabling spring debugging, I figure out it is failing on some unknown properties, I had to annotate my class with @JsonIgnoreProperties. Now it works.